# How to get a specific type of child elements

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery to get an anchor tag and its contents but the method I'm using also grabs the span tag next to the anchor tag. I want to be able to get the respective `<a></a>` only in the all `.chosen` elements. How can I do this?

```js
$('.chosen').each(function(){
  var cur = $(this).html();
  encodeURIComponent(cur);
  $('#custom_crumb').append(cur);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="chosen" style="display: none;">
  <a rel="nofollow" href="http://website.co.uk/shop/?filter_colour=amber">Amber</a>
  
  <span class="count">(14)</span>
</li>

<div id="custom_crumb"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the *inner* HTML of the anchor, then:

```
var cur = $(this).find("a").html();
```

If you want the *outer* HTML of it, then:

```
var cur = $(this).find("a").prop("outerHTML");
```

Live example of the `outerHTML` version, since I think that's what you want:

```js
$('.chosen').each(function(){
  var cur = $(this).find("a").prop("outerHTML");
  $('#custom_crumb').append(cur);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="chosen" style="display: none;">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="http://website.co.uk/shop/?filter_colour=amber">Amber</a>

    <span class="count">(14)</span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="custom_crumb"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I removed the `encodeURIComponent(cur);` line, which doesn't do anything since you haven't used the return value. If you want it for some reason (it seems like an odd thing to do), add it back but with `cur = encodeURIComponent(cur);`.

Comment: Or `$('a',this)[0].outerHTML;`

Comment: @Zenoo - You don't want the `prop` in that. (Edit: Ah, you edited. Note that that form of `$()` just ends up doing `find` anyway.) The reason I did it the way I did it above is that if there is no anchor, using `prop()` will give you `undefined` rather than throwing an error.

Comment: I mistyped the `prop`, sorry about that ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use .first().

```
$('.chosen > a').first()
```

**Note**: It will return the element itself use .html() to get the contents (HTML).
And it'll work even if you had multiple anchors in your .chosen.
It will select first anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specified the element in

> $(this).html()

In this li it has two element span and a. For specific element you need to tell jquery that i want to need only a element.By

> $(this).find('a').html()

```js
$('.chosen').each(function() {
  var cur = $(this).find('a').eq(0).html();
  $('#custom_crumb').append(cur);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="chosen" style="display: none;">
  <a rel="nofollow" href="http://website.co.uk/shop/?filter_colour=amber">Amber</a>

  <span class="count">(14)</span>
</li>

<div id="custom_crumb"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to find `a` tag first.

```js
$('.chosen').each(function(){
  var cur = $(this).find('a').html();
  encodeURIComponent(cur);
  $('#custom_crumb').append(cur);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="chosen" style="display: none;">
  <a rel="nofollow" href="http://website.co.uk/shop/?filter_colour=amber">Amber</a>
  
  <span class="count">(14)</span>
</li>
</ul>

<div id="custom_crumb"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the `a` element directly in the selector:

```js
$('.chosen a').each(function(){
  var cur = $(this).html();
  $('#custom_crumb').append(cur);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="chosen" style="display: none;">
  <a rel="nofollow" href="http://website.co.uk/shop/?filter_colour=amber">Amber</a>
  
  <span class="count">(14)</span>
</li>

<div id="custom_crumb"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.chosen a')`, it will select anchor tag inside class `chosen`

```
$('.chosen a').each(function(){
  var cur = $(this).html();
  encodeURIComponent(cur);
  $('#custom_crumb').append(cur);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers just ignore the fact that `.html()` is obviously the wrong function for what youre trying to do.

You can either select the anchor tag and append it to somewhere, or you can clone it. Both ways are far more performant that reading and re-parsing html:

```
var crumb = $('#custom_crumb');

$('.chosen').each(function(){
  var anchor = $(this).find('a').first();

  crumb.append(anchor);

  // or, to keep the a in the <li>

  crumb.append(anchor.clone());
});
```